# Como montar uma query genérica usando a nativequery do jpa

Tags: sql, jpa

Considere a seguinte tabela:

tabela: info_pessoas

||row ||nome  ||sobrenome   ||nacionalidade ||time_do_coracao
|1|marcelo |aragao       |brasil         |sp
|2 |maria   |fonseca      |brasil         |sp
|3 |joao    |timotio      |brasil         |palmeiras
|4 |marcelo |vasconcelos  |brasil         |corinthians

Imagine que eu tenho um formulário com todos esses campos, onde nenhum deles é obrigatório.
Preciso levar em consideração apenas os campos digitados pelo usuário, logo se o usuário preencher o campo nacionalidade = brasil e tipe_do_coracao = sp, a aplicação deve trazer as linhas 1 e 2.

na minha aplicação jpa eu fiz o seguinte:

```
em.createNativeQuery ("select nome from info_pessoas where nome = ? and sobrenome = ? and nacionalidade = ? and time_do_coracao = ?")
```

obs: os "?" serão preenchidos com os valores digitados pelo usuário, nesse caso o 3 e o 4 "?" foram preenchidos com brasil e sp respectivamente.

O problema é que nenhuma linha esta sendo retornada, qual a maneira certa de montar a query?

Answer (score 0):

Felipe,

Quando for criar uma nativeQuery pense como você faria isso diretamente no banco de dados, ou seja, o que funcionar na sua SQL vai funcionar no createNativeQuery.
Isso funciona:

```
    em.createNativeQuery("select nome from info_pessoas where nacionalidade = 'Brasil' and time_do_coracao = 'SP'").getResultList();
```

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, porem eu preciso montar a clausula where da quey dinamicamente, logo o exemplo acima não daria certo.

Comment: Felipe, a verdade é que para montar dinamicamente uma query teríamos que está concatenando string, e isso não é uma boa prática. Se você quiser eu tenho um exemplo com Criteria do Hibernate. Nos seus projetos você usa Maven?

Comment: Felipe, você também poderia usar JPQL que será mas fácil ainda. Olha, não coloquei um exemplo deste aqui porque a sua pergunta foi para uma NativeQuery. Faz uma outra pergunta assim: "Como montar uma query genérica usando jpa".